# WPF как "перевернуть" DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть DataGrid, обычно он заполнять построчно, а как заполнять его по стобцу?
Тоесть не так заполнять:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4132829/6766879

Comment: Возможно вам подойдет [DataGrid2D](https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D)